# Spring Controller Method annotated with @ResponseBody, @GET takes long time to generate respone

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-annotations, spring-restcontroller

Spring Controller Method annotated with `@ResponseBody` takes long time to generate JSON response when I annotate it with `@GET` HTTP Method annotation

While the same method when annotated with `@POST` (keeping `@ResponseBody` annotation intact), the JSON response is generated quickly.

`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is configured in our application along with `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

I can say that response generation is taking time since after returning from the controller method, the call back on JavaScript Ajax request takes longer to get called when `@GET` is used on method as compared to when `@POST` is used on method.

Can someone please help me understand what is taking time.

Or any help in understanding what all spring interceptors/handlers are getting called in response generation, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `@Get` and `@Post` to influence the behavior as those are JAX-RS annotations and not spring annotations. So either you aren't using Spring MVC, or are doing some weird things.

Comment: Are you using any custom filters?

Comment: Yes, we are using Custom Filters for GZiping all the content of a GET Request.


Thanks alot, for bringing my attention towards that.